# Check if a percentage of a list contains a specific string

Tags: python

I have a list :

```
mylist = ['STN1', 'STRN2', 'BCN2', 'BCN3', 'None', 'None', 'STN5, 'STN6']
```

I'm trying to find a solution to check if a percentage of the list contains a specific string.

So in my case I want to know if at least 40% of the list elements contains `'ST'` in them.

I tried something like this :

```
second_list = []
for element in mylist:
    if 'ST' in element:
        second_list.append(element)
print(second_list)
size = len(mylist)
size2 = len(second_list)
if size2 >= ((4*size) / 10):
    print("true")
else:
    print("false")
```

Is there a simpler solution than what I have at the moment?

Comment: You don't need to create a second list, just count them.

Comment: Better/simpler in what way? Fewer lines of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generator expression `(1 for s in mylist if 'ST' in s)` will give you a sequence of `1`s for each string in your list that contains "ST". `sum` them. Divide that by the length of the list. That gives you a number between 0 and 1. Check if that's >= 0.4.

```
if sum(1 for s in mylist if 'ST' in s) / len(mylist) >= 0.4:
    print('true')
else:
    print('false')
```

---

You *could* write that as `sum('ST' in s for s in mylist)`, because summing `True`s and `False`s will have the same result, but I prefer to be more explicit…

Answer (score 2):

Using `statistics.mean`, you could do the whole thing just like this:

```
print(mean('ST' in s for s in mylist) >= 0.4)
```

(It does print `True`/`False` instead of `true`/`false`, but that might not matter.)